# Conditional expectation of an Ito integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

Given $M_t = \int_0^t uB_u dB_u$. For $0\leq s \leq t$, I would like to compute $E[M^2_t | F_s]$.

The closest thing that I can think of is Ito's isometry. But here we have the conditional expectation, which makes it inapplicable. Additionally, while $M_t$ itself is a martingale, $M_t^2$ isn't in general. I would appreciate suggestions how on to solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: $M_t = \int_0^s u B_u dB_u + \int_s^t u B_u dB_u$ and the latter integral is independent of $\mathcal{F}_s$, while the former is $\mathcal{F}_s$ measurable.

Comment: Another hint: By Ito's formula $M_t^2=2\int_0^tM_u\,dM_u+\int_0^tu^2B_u^2\,du$ and $\int_0^tM_u\,dM_u$ is a martingale.